# Alignment changing while iterating over array inside HTML <div>

Tags: html, angularjs

I am iterating over the array and displaying values using HTML component.

Please find my HTML markup below:

```
    <div ng-show="showHistory" class="history-log"> 
      <h5> {{'claim.group.history.label'|translate}}<a href="" ng-click="showHistory=false" class="btn-close">&times;</a></h5>
      <ul class="history-items">
        <li ng-repeat="history in claimGroupingHistories | orderBy : 'lastModifiedAt'">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <label>{{'users.history.dateTime'|translate}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div id="historyActionTime_{{$index}}" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{history.lastModifiedAt | date:'d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <label>{{'users.history.user'|translate}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div id="historyUser_{{$index}}" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{history.createdBy}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <label>{{'claimgroup.history.oldvalueselected'|translate}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div layout="column">
              <div ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected.split(',')" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{oldValue}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <label>{{'claimgroup.history.newvalueselected'|translate}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div id="historyNewValueSelected_{{$index}}" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{history.newValueSelected}}    </div>
          </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

While displaying values, if more values are available then, the alignment is getting collapsed.

Please find the attached screenshot.

Some of the values are coming in left hand side, actually all values should come on the Right Hand Side itself.

If i have to show the `label` & `value` inside the table means. How to bring the iterating values inside table.?

[image]

Comment: nothing to do with your problem, but if all screen sizes are col 4, why not just use col-4 instead of defining each size as 4? It will help cut down on errors like this: `col-lg-4 col-md col-sm-4 col-xs-4` where you forgot to add the 4 on the `md`

Comment: @Pete - Thanks that i have missed and added now. But the value alignment is not proper yet.

Comment: for a mobile screen,  use col-sm-12 & col-xs-12 instead of col-sm-4 & col-xs-4

Comment: Maybe because in all cases you have `class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"` while your outer div has `layout="column"` instead of `col`s for the "Old Value Selected". Surely copying the code from "New Value Selected" should fix it since it looks fine there.

Comment: @Protozoid - is that possible to have table only for `Old Value Selected`?

Comment: The native markup elements of a definition list <dl>, <dd>, <dt>, is better suited to this, as that is exactly what it was designed to do.